# Cannot upload media in Wordpress. Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I cannot get around this! This is the first time I have tried uploading anything and I get this error. I have searched multiple forums and have had no luck. I've changed permissions to 755 and also 777, still no luck. I upgraded to the newest version of wordpress also, 3.8.

Im running this on a Ubuntu server using apache. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP?  DSO, CGI, FastCGI, suphp?

Also what folder are you changing permissions to? it should be the uploads folder within wp-content.

The preferred, and most secure, is to assure your PHP is running as CGI, FastCGI, or suPHP and make sure the wp-content/uploads folder belongs to the user and not root.

Comment: I had to use the gui instead of the command line, but your solution worked for me. I changed the permissions and ownership of the wp-content folder to the user and gave read write access. Thanks for your help.